Redirect between domains on same IP, without changing the url in the adressbar
Situation:
I have a wordpress website on my domain newpapa.br-workshop.purplepanda.be (staging)
I have a few domains redirecting with a CNAME or A-records (like in this example: papatest.purplepanda.be
When I go to papatest.purplepanda.be/final-test, I want to redirect to the page '/blackbear-test-page/' on my Wordpress website (on same IP because the last domain is connected through DNS records to the first one). Im doing this in my htacces file with:
#DOMAIN REWRITE papatest.purplepanda.be/final-test
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^papatest\.purplepanda\.be/final-test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://newpapa.br-workshop.purplepanda.be/blackbear-test-page/ [L]

This all works!
The problem:
I want to keep the original url (papatest.purplepanda.be/final-test) in the adressbar, after the redirect to https://newpapa.br-workshop.purplepanda.be/blackbear-test-page/
Disclaimer
I already looked online, and looked like the anwser was easy: changing [L, R=301] to [L], but that didn't fix the problem.
The solutions in the first 4 threads popping up did not work for me.

If the substitution URL is an absolute one, and the host name doesn't match the current one, then you will get an external redirect, R flag or not. You gave little details about your WP setup (is it a multisite, serving different content under the different access domains, or same content for all, just different domain "aliases"), but most likely you will need to proxy this request (look into mod_proxy, and the RewriteRule P flag.)

It's not completely a multisite, but a platform based on wordpress we use to build landngpages and push them to other domains.
We have a working v1 for bit more than a year now, but there all the redirection is handled with a plugin. It's not really user friendly, so I'm trying to build my own solution for this.
So the scnenario is:
We build pages on that Wordpress. The user can add domains and link them trough DNS. Once linked they can add mapping: Saying this page should show on domainA/slug
I did look into the P tag before, and it didn't work, but maybe I have to look again. Thx!
